# How do I insert and update array columns in Node-Postgres?

Tags: node-postgres

I have the following table in Postgres:

```
_id: integer, user_id: integer, items: Array
```

I wish to insert the following into the table:

```
1, 1, [{productId: 1, size: 'large', quantity: 5}]
```

Next I wish to update the row with the following:

```
1, 1, [{productId: 1, size: 'small', quantity: 3}]
```

How do I do this in node-postgres?

Pseudocode:

```
update cart 
set items.quantity = 3 
where cart._id = 1
and cart.items.product_id = 1
and cart.items.size='large'
```

Comment: Do you want to update only `items` and `replace` or update `user_id` as well

Comment: Update only items. See the pseudocode I added.